# Reduce amount of AJAX calls for autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I was sending the AJAX query on the keyup for my search textbox but what I want to do is wait until 1 second after the user stops typing.

Code I have:

```
searchBar = $('#searchBar');
searchBar.timerID = null;
searchBar.textBox = $('#searchBar > input[name="q"]');
searchBar.textBox.sendQuery = function(){
  alert('SEND AJAX HERE');
  searchBar.timerID = null;
};
searchBar.textBox.keyup(function() {
  if(searchBar.timerID){ clearTimeout(searchBar.timerID); }
  searchBar.timerID = setTimeout(searchBar.textBox.sendQuery, 1000);
});
```

It seems to work, but is the the best way to about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [plugin](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/bindwithdelay-jquery-plugin/) will fire an event after a short delay.  You could then use something like the following:

```
$(searchBar).bindWithDelay("keyup", callback, 1000);
```

Comment: I don't know which I like more. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

It isn't good practise to be polluting the jQuery object returned like `$('#searchBar').value = 'blah'` -- instead you should ultilise the `.data` method:

You don't really need searchBar at all, just put the timer on the corresponding input element. I always prefix jQuery objects with `$` for better clarification.

```
$input = $('#searchBar input[name="q"]');

var sendQuery = function() {
  alert('SEND AJAX HERE');
};

$input.keyup(function() {
  var timer = $(this).data('timerID');
  if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  $(this).data('timerID', setTimeout(sendQuery, 1000));
});
```

Comment: Not really an answer to my question, but a good tip. Forgot about the data attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Ben Alman's debounce plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/